# WHERE clause gives poor query plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, where-clause, sql-execution-plan

I'm not sure how best to tune this query and/ or indexes to avoid a blunt FORCE ORDER hint.

This main query runs fine, currently returns 0 rows in 0 seconds:

```
SELECT  S1.ID, S.LOAD_DATE,  s.Deleted,S1.HUB_FORM_ID
FROM #TMP S

INNER JOIN HUB_FORM H1 ON 
H1.Form_ID = S.HUB_FORM_BK
INNER JOIN  HUB_ORG H2 ON 
H2.Organisation_ID = S.HUB_ORG_BK
INNER JOIN  HUB_PERSON H3 ON 
H3.person_id = S.HUB_PERSON_BK
INNER JOIN  HUB_EVENT H4 ON 
H4.job_id = S.HUB_EVENT_BK
INNER JOIN  HUB_WORKFLOW_STEP H5 ON 
H5.step_id = S.HUB_WORKFLOW_STEP_BK

INNER JOIN LNK_FORM_ENTITY S1 ON
H1.HUB_FORM_ID = S1.HUB_FORM_ID AND H2.HUB_ORG_ID = S1.HUB_ORG_ID AND H3.HUB_PERSON_ID = S1.HUB_PERSON_ID AND H4.HUB_EVENT_ID = S1.HUB_EVENT_ID AND H5.HUB_WORKFLOW_STEP_ID = S1.HUB_WORKFLOW_STEP_ID

INNER JOIN DK_SAT_LNK_FORM_ENTITY S2 ON 
 S1.ID = S2.Parent_ID
```

Adding a WHERE clause on S2.LOAD_DATE_TO makes it run and run (killed off after a minute or two).

```
WHERE S2.LOAD_DATE_TO = '31/12/9999'
```

I'm not sure why that happens as:

1. Without the filter, no rows are returned, so it can make no difference.
2. The index used for the table containing this field in the good plan (with no date filter), already contains that field as the second key field so I'd have thought any additional cost is negligible

NB - it doesn't always return 0 rows, but it needs to run (and complete in a reasonable time) whether rows are returned or not.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [JM_TEST_190221_2] ON [dbo].[DK_SAT_LNK_FORM_ENTITY]
(
    [Parent_ID] ASC,
    [LOAD_DATE_TO] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The live query plan shows it running through millions of rows in the LNK_ and DK_ tables and subsequently joined tables, whereas in the original plan it shows actual number of rows = 56 (56 executions - expected 1 row) on the LNK_ table and 0 actual rows (56 executions) on the DK_ table.

If I add `OPTION  (FORCE ORDER)` after the WHERE clause, it runs in 0 seconds again, with a different query plan to the original good one.

Clearly that resolves the issue in the short term, but I'm wary of using such a blunt instrument given that it may not always be the optimal choice as data changes over time.

*Edit*
I have tried updating statistics with FULL SCAN, and rebuilding key indexes but it had no impact.

Query plans below - any tips or explanation gratefully received!

---

Original good plan (actual plan): no WHERE clause : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyG3SwTZd

Poor plan (from live query plan at point killed off) : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJpBSPpWO

Good plan with FORCE ORDER hint : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJqxUvT-d

Comment: To confirm, you're asking how to better tune a query that correctly returns 0 rows?

Comment: It doesn't always return zero rows, but the query needs to run (and complete... and in a reasonable time) whether rows are returned or not.

Comment: Did you try to update statistics? Maybe they are out of date for some tables. Did you rebuilt your indexes?

I can't tell the internal reason for the chosen query plan, but the execution engine decided that for the query with the `WHERE` clause the worse plan would fit better. It seems like these bad choices can happen with multiple `JOINs`. The `FORCE ORDER` option exists for a reason, I guess...

Comment: I updated all stats with FULL SCAN and rebuilt the key indexes but no impact unfortunately.

Comment: Apply the FORCE ORDER hint, sometimes the optimiser gets it wrong, there is nothing wrong with telling it what you want it to do.  Hints are there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, your issue is that `HUB_FORM` is selective enough that it is limiting the rows down to 0 at the very beginning. But the optimizer does not realize that and therefore it is reversing the order of the joins.

To enforce the order without hammering the rest of the query via `FORCE ORDER`, we have two options:

1. Pre-compute the join of `#TMP, HUB_FORM` into a temp table or table variable. This can often cause a fair bit of extra IO.
2. A much better option is to persuade the optimizer to compute the join first, but without using explicit hints.

This is often best done by putting the join inside a subquery with a `SELECT TOP`, but you may need to modify this by adding one or two further joins.

```sql
SELECT  S1.ID, S.LOAD_DATE, s.Deleted, S1.HUB_FORM_ID
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (9223372036854775807) S.*
    FROM #TMP S
    INNER JOIN HUB_FORM H1 ON 
        H1.Form_ID = S.HUB_FORM_BK
) S
INNER JOIN  HUB_ORG H2 ON 
H2.Organisation_ID = S.HUB_ORG_BK
INNER JOIN  HUB_PERSON H3 ON 
H3.person_id = S.HUB_PERSON_BK
INNER JOIN  HUB_EVENT H4 ON 
H4.job_id = S.HUB_EVENT_BK
INNER JOIN  HUB_WORKFLOW_STEP H5 ON 
H5.step_id = S.HUB_WORKFLOW_STEP_BK

INNER JOIN LNK_FORM_ENTITY S1 ON
H1.HUB_FORM_ID = S1.HUB_FORM_ID AND H2.HUB_ORG_ID = S1.HUB_ORG_ID AND H3.HUB_PERSON_ID = S1.HUB_PERSON_ID AND H4.HUB_EVENT_ID = S1.HUB_EVENT_ID AND H5.HUB_WORKFLOW_STEP_ID = S1.HUB_WORKFLOW_STEP_ID

INNER JOIN DK_SAT_LNK_FORM_ENTITY S2 ON 
 S1.ID = S2.Parent_ID
```

If that doesn't work, you may be able to persuade it by changing the `TOP` to a variable, and adding an `OPTIMIZE FOR` hint at the end:

```sql
DECLARE @topRows bigint = 9223372036854775807;

SELECT  S1.ID, S.LOAD_DATE, s.Deleted, S1.HUB_FORM_ID
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (@topRows) S.*
    FROM #TMP S
    INNER JOIN HUB_FORM H1 ON 
        H1.Form_ID = S.HUB_FORM_BK
) S
INNER JOIN  HUB_ORG H2 ON 
.........
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@topRows = 1));
```

This causes the optimizer to think it will only get 1 row out of the join, but actually allows more rows if that is the case at a runtime.

**Note that none of this changes the essential semantics of the query**

Comment: Thanks for this well-explained comment and suggestions. To clarify, HUB_FORM is not selective enough to reduce rows to 0 at the beginning - in the original query it returns 56 rows. I have tried both suggestions, and they do both work as well as FORCE ORDER, minor differences but the IO statistics are almost the same. I am wary of optimizing for 1 as sometimes thousands of rows may be returned. Still definitely preferable to current situation (plan 2) but I'm on the fence as to whether it's preferable to FORCE ORDER in terms of  it remaining optimal for different situations.